# Can not locate typescript external modules in bower package

Tags: requirejs, typescript, amd

I made a bower package with typescript source(external modules). In another project, I installed my bower package using

```
bower install wrath
```

and referred that package with amd require.

```
import Model = require('wrath/Model');
```

Then tsc compiler give an error `error TS2307: Cannot find external module`. I can't figure out how to make the compiler know it should lookup that module in bower_components folder.

I have a folder structure like this.

```
app
    main.ts
bower_components
    wrath
        Model.ts
        View.ts
        ...
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

I actually found a way to work around this by making a symbolic link of bower package directory along side with the app directory. Looking for a better way.

Comment: Did you come up with a nice solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to make the compiler know it should lookup that module in bower_components

There is no solution other than *hard references* for now:

```
import Model  = require('./bower_components/wrath/Model');
```

Note: there is great desire to support `node_modules` : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/247

Note: grunt-ts can help you make these references : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#transforms

Comment: grunt-ts transform looks rather complex, enforcing many modification to source code. If no better solution exists for now, perhaps I'lll stick to my symbolic link solution for now.

Comment: cool. TIP : I expect `require('wrath/Model');` to fail at runtime. Unless you use `node_modules` and not `bower_components`. But you might be using something that resolves it correctly.

Comment: Requirejs can be setup like this.  `requirejs.config({
 baseUrl: './app',
 packages: [
  {
   name: 'wrath',
   location: '../bower_components/wrath/src'
  }
 ]
});
` Would be nice if tsc have similar options.

Comment: I'm struggling with bower+amd+typescript and I've boiled it down to all `/bower_components/` references need to become `/../` references after bower flattens the structure (to avoid typings, deps, paths).  It's too bad TSC is not bower_components aware.